# Generating a variable frequency PWM signal for AVR

Tags: avr, pwm

I want to generate a PWM signal with variable frequency and a fixed duty cycle(50%). Frequency should vary between 0-25KHz. This is for a ATMEGA32U4 microcontroller and I'm writing it in C using Atmel Studio. I did read the datasheet but I can't get my head around on how to do the calculations and which modes I should use. After going through different tutorials I found that its best to use CTC mode.

How do I select which prescalar I should use since the frequency is a variable? Do I need to use interrupts? Any help on how to setup these timer registers are appreciated.

Comment: You should try to ask something more specific. The question as it stands would require "another tutorial" as an answer. What was the problem with the tutorials you read? Maybe quote sections/calculations of a tutorial you do not understand.

Answer (score 5):

The 32U4 has timers identical to the 328P on which I did tests for your problem. I used Timer 1 which offers the best resolution. This timer can be run in CTC mode and channel A can be bound to a fixed output pin in toggle-on-compare-match. This makes the setup extremely simple and requires no interrupt logic. The frequency can be controlled simply by writing to OCR1A <strike>(this register is double buffered so that changes to frequency should be glitch-free)</strike>*.

In CTC mode Timer 1 has an output frequency of:

```
f n x = f_cpu / (2 * n * (1 + x))
```

where n is the pre-scale value and x the overflow compare register. Exploring the possible frequency ranges on a 16MHz clock gives:

```
|   N |  f-min |     f-max |     r-min |   r-max   | x-100 | x-25k |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+
|   1 | 122.1  | 8,000,000 | 4,000,000 | 0.0019    |   n/a |   319 |
|   8 |  15.3  | 1,000,000 |   500,000 | 0.00023   | 9,999 |    39 |
|  64 |   1.91 |   125,000 |    62,500 | 0.000029  | 1,249 |     4 |
| 256 |   0.49 |    31,250 |    15,625 | 0.0000073 |   311 |   n/a |
|1024 |   0.12 |     7,812 |     3,906 | 0.0000018 |    77 |   n/a |
```

where N is the pre-scale setting, f-min & f-max the minimum and maximum achievable frequencies r-min & r-max the minimum and maximum frequency resolution and finally x-100 & x-25k the required values for OCR1A for 100Hz and 25kHz output respectively.

For a complete worked example here is a program that cycles through frequencies 1Hz, 2, 5, 10... 500kHz in 2 second steps, sufficient to observe the workings on a scope:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

struct CTC1
{
    static void setup()
    {
        // CTC mode with TOP-OCR1A

        TCCR1A = 0;
        TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12);

        // toggle channel A on compare match

        TCCR1A = (TCCR1A & ~(_BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1A0))) | _BV(COM1A0);

        // set channel A bound pin to output mode

        DDRB |= _BV(1); // PB1 on 328p, use _BV(5) for PB5 on 32U4
    }

    static void set_freq(float f)
    {
        static const float f1 = min_freq(1), f8 = min_freq(8), f64 = min_freq(64), f256 = min_freq(256);

        uint16_t n;

        if (f >= f1)        n = 1;
        else if (f >= f8)   n = 8;
        else if (f >= f64)  n = 64;
        else if (f >= f256) n = 256;
        else                n = 1024;

        prescale(n);

        OCR1A = static_cast<uint16_t>(round(F_CPU / (2 * n * f) - 1));
    }

    static void prescale(uint16_t n)
    {
        uint8_t bits = 0;

        switch (n)
        {
            case    1:  bits = _BV(CS10);               break;
            case    8:  bits = _BV(CS11);               break;
            case   64:  bits = _BV(CS11) | _BV(CS10);   break;
            case  256:  bits = _BV(CS12);               break;
            case 1024:  bits = _BV(CS12) | _BV(CS10);   break;
            default:    bits = 0;
        }

        TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & ~(_BV(CS12) | _BV(CS11) | _BV(CS10))) | bits;
    }

    static inline float min_freq(uint16_t n)
    {
        return ceil(F_CPU / (2 * n * 65536));
    }
};

void setup()
{
    CTC1::setup();
}

void loop()
{
    for (uint8_t x = 0; x < 6; ++x)
        for (uint8_t y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
        {
            float k = y > 0 ? (y > 1 ? 5 : 2) : 1;

            CTC1::set_freq(k * pow(10, x));
            _delay_ms(2000);
        }
}

int main()
{
    setup();
    for (;;)
        loop();
}
```

The signal is observable on PB1 (digital pin 9 on an Arduino Uno). Note that on 32U4 channel-A is bound to PB5.

As Aleksander Z. kindly commented, the OCR1A register is not double-buffered in CTC mode. When switching frequencies this can lead to severe glitches, e.g.:

[image]

Depending on the application this may be easily fixed by busy-looping (though this may not work well for very high frequencies or may cause unacceptable delays under very low frequencies):

```
while (TCNT1 > x)
    ;
OCR1A = x;
```

Producing:

[image]

Comment: _The frequency can be controlled simply by writing to OCR1A (this register is double buffered so that changes to frequency should be glitch-free)._ No, **OCR1A isn't double buffered in CTC mode:** [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_datasheet.pdf), page 162 says: _Note: Changing TOP to a value close to BOTTOM while the counter is running must be done with care, since the CTC mode does not provide double buffering. If the new value written to OCR1A is lower than the current value of TCNT1, the counter will miss the compare match._

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I have updated the post accordingly. Btw, if you have better fixes for dealing with these glitches, please post.

Comment: I got the answer: datasheet, page 164: _A frequency waveform output with 50% duty cycle can be achieved in Fast PWM mode by selecting OC1A to toggle its logical level on each compare match (COM1A[1:0]=0x1). This applies only if OCR1A is used to define the TOP value (WGM1[3:0]=0xF).
The waveform generated will have a maximum frequency of f_OC1A = f_clk_I/O / 2 when OCR1A is set to zero (0x0000). This feature is similar to the OC1A toggle in CTC mode, except the double buffer feature of the Output Compare unit is enabled in the Fast PWM mode._

Answer (score 0):

I do not use ATMEGA32U4 at all I like AT32UC3 much more so sorry no exact code ... but
why don't you just set timer to twice of the desired frequency and toggle pin inside it ? as your duty is always 50% that should work. The frequency update can be done on each even or on every `n-th` ISR counter/timer call ...

something like:

```
const int n=10; // must be even to ensure 50% duty
volatile int ix=0;
volatile int frequency=10000;
isr_timercounter()
 {
 // clear IRQ
 // toggle pin
 ix++; if (ix>=n)
  {
  ix=0;
  // set timer/counter to 2*frequency
  }
 }

void main()
 {
 // init timer/counter
 for (;;)
  {
  //do your stuff
  frequency = ???;
  }
 }
```